# SaveAll JpaRepository method - Audit4j java version not supported

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm trying to load data into the database from a file when the application starts. The file mapping to the list of entities works fine, but when I call saveAll method I get a strange error -
`Audit4j:ERROR Your Java version (13.0.2) is not supported for Audit4j.  see http://audit4j.org/errors#javaVersion for further details. Audit4j:ERROR Failed to initialize Audit4j: Java version is not supported.`
I changed the version, error remained the same, and what does Java version have to do with it, if logging works fine without call to saveAll.
I already have the functionality to load data through the controller, and tried to load same file through it - everything works fine. What can be the cause of problem?

Code:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MetaLoader {
    private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    private EntityMetaRepository entityMetaRepository;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        Resource metaResource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:metadata/metadata.json");
        log.info("**MetaLoader | resource exists?=" + metaResource.exists());
        File metaFile = metaResource.getFile();

        // mapping
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<Meta> metaList;
        CollectionType metaListType = mapper.getTypeFactory()
                    .constructCollectionType(List.class, Meta.class);

        metaList= mapper.readValue(metaFile, metaListType);


        log.info("**MetaLoader | metaList=" + metaList.toString());

        if (!metaList.isEmpty()) {
            log.info("**MetaLoader | saving metadata...");
            List<EntityMeta> entityMetaList = metaList.stream().map(EntityMeta::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
            try {
                entityMetaRepository.saveAll(entityMetaList);
            } catch (EntityExistsException e) {
                log.error("**MetaLoader | something went wrong=" + e.getMessage() + "\n" + e.getCause());
            }
        }
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class MetaApi {
    @Autowired private EntityMetaRepository entityMetaRepository;

    @PostMapping(value = "/meta", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> postMetaTableFile(MultipartFile file) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<Meta> metaList = null;
        try {
            CollectionType metaListType = mapper.getTypeFactory()
                    .constructCollectionType(List.class, Meta.class);
            metaList = mapper.readValue(file.getBytes(), metaListType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ErrorResponse response = new ErrorResponse().code(400).type("BAD REQUEST").message("Malformed file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try { 
            List<EntityMeta> entityMetaList = metaList.stream().map(EntityMeta::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
            entityMetaRepository.saveAll(entityMetaList);
        } catch (EntityExistsException e) {
            throw new ResponseException(e.getMessage(),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        ErrorResponse response = new ErrorResponse().code(200).type("OK").message("OK");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: What has logging to do with this error? You are using some auditing framework **Audit4J** which doesn't support Java 13. So either downgrade Java to a supported version, Upgrade Audit4J to a version that supports Java 13 or stop using the framework. Judging from the fact that **Audit4J** hasn't really been updated since 2018 I suspect you are out of luck on upgrading that.

Comment: @M.Deinum - yes, i see that. But I'm confused by the fact that the error appears only when i trying  to save data; if you get data through the same repository, everything works fine. So I think maybe the error is in something else, i just dont see it

Comment: Audit information is only written when things change, not when things are read.